# What is the most reliable way to get the current UTC or zulu time regardless of user location or time settings?

Tags: iphone, ios, datetime, time, timezone

Example: User local time is 10:30 pm PST in reality. Device can show 10:30 pm if user has internet and lets iOS automatically configure time and time zones. But some users disable this and do it by hand and get it wrong. For example no correct daylight saving time. I know from a friend who walked around with wrong time offset by 1 hour because of this.

I want to know the exact time in Zulu time or UTC-0 regardless of user location. What is the safest way to find out so my app can alert "NOW is Zulu 0" or "NOW is UTC-0" and it is correct. How?

Comment: Access an ntp server.

Comment: Can you give example? Is there a web service?

Comment: There are plenty of public ntp servers. I suppose there are nice public web services too. Do some searching on the topic. I'm sure you'll find plenty of info. I've never tried it with iOS myself but it can't be too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the time zone to UTC using

```
NSTimeZone *timeZoneUTC = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:timeZoneUTC];
```

and then get the current time using `NSDate *today = [NSDate date];`